# Schema.org for table of contents

Tags: google-search, schema.org, search-results

I've noticed Google has taken some of my table of contents and put into the SERPs. I don't have any Schema.org embedded on these pages at all. But I do like the result.

I've searched for a table of contents schema and come up with zero. Other than `Table` schema which I'm pretty much sure is not what I want.

To be clear, I've a list at the top my page which links to headings throughout the page with all the contents. It's not even in list format, just `<p>` paragraphs. (Maybe Google sees this as a list instead of a TOC?)

Is there such a thing as a table of contents schema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't look like schema.org has a markup for book table of contents. However, there is a markup for [TOC in a Federal Regulations](http://cfpb.github.io/regulations-schema/toc/) and you can see how they marked up their own "[Table of Contents](https://schema.org/docs/automotive.html)," it is mostly just a unordered list element.

Answer (score 0):

> “It works like this: news organizations that publish data in the form of tables can add additional structured data to make the dataset parts of the page easier to identify for use in relevant Search features.”

This is what you are looking for, [directly from Google](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/dataset).

Answer (score 0):

What about using
"@type": "BreadcrumbList",
and list items in the TOC?

This sounds logical but I'm not Google.